# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'cursor' Error in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

```
myresults = db.persona.aggregate([{"$match": {'$or': [{"id": {"$gte": 1}},{"id": {"$lte": 20000}}]}},{ "$project": {"id": 1,"ward": 1}},{'cursor': {'batchSize': 0}}],useCursor=False)
for result in myresults:
    db.persona.update_many({"_id":result["_id"]},{"$set": {column_name:df1.iloc[:,m][list(result.values())[1]]}})
```

Error in OperationFailure: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'cursor'

How can i solve this

Comment: Please format your code and fix its indentation.

Comment: What is the version of `mongodb` ?

Comment: 3.4.9 version of my mongodb

Comment: `cursor` is not an arrgegation stage, but an option. It sould be outside of the pipeline, see [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error in OperationFailure: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'cursor'

The method
[aggregate()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) in PyMongo specifies that the first parameter is `pipeline`, which is a list of aggregation pipeline stages. The error is because `cursor` is not a valid [Aggregation Pipeline Stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).

So you can correct this with:

```
myresults = db.persona.aggregate([{"$match": {"$or": [{"id": {"$gte": 1}},{"id": {"$lte": 20000}}]}},{ "$project": {"id": 1,"ward": 1}}])

for result in myresults:
   print(result) # process result document.
```

Note that the parameter `useCursor` is deprecated, and will be removed in PyMongo v4.0+. Based on your example snippet, you would want to return a [cursor](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor) that you can iterate over.

> {'cursor': {'batchSize': 0}}

Also worth noting that this is a cursor option for [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) via [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/), perhaps that's where the confusion comes from.

Comment: what if I have a column name {"name": "Jhon walker"} and search by passing only the first name how can do it in django I have tried doing [{"$match": {"$or": [{"name": {"$regex": "/^jhon/"}}] but it's working